# Countdown to January 1 2016

Tags: javascript, html, mathematics

*Already read [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75404/new-year-countdown), but OP is using some other method.*

My [website](http://2016newyear.weebly.com/) finds the time till new year. But [this website](http://www.timeanddate.com/counters/newyear.html) claims to be accurate to the tenth of a second. So what I found out was my timer and their timer is off by about a minute.

```
var daysSpan = document.getElementById("days");
var hoursSpan = document.getElementById("hours");
var minutesSpan = document.getElementById("minutes");
var secondsSpan = document.getElementById("seconds");
var c=1;
function updateClock(){
    var t = Date.parse('January 1 2016 00:01:05') - Date.parse(new Date());
    if (t<=0 && c==1)
    {
        c--;
        window.open("http://www.its2016.weebly.com","_self");
    }
    var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
    var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
    var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
    var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
    daysSpan.innerHTML = days;
    hoursSpan.innerHTML = hours;
    minutesSpan.innerHTML = minutes;
    secondsSpan.innerHTML = seconds;
}
setInterval(updateClock,1000);
```

My area of suspicion is this, I have a feeling that all the divisions and multiplications are making it very inaccurate.

```
    var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
    var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
    var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
    var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
```

So how can I make my calculations more accurate?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Code Review. "So how can I make my calculations more accurate?" is not asking for a review, rather help on how to make calculations more accurate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not asking for a review.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var diff = Date.parse('January 1 2016')-Date.now();
// correct timezone shift, because Date(0) is GMT 00:00
diff += (new Date).getTimezoneOffset() * 60*1000;
var days = Math.floor(diff / 864e5);
diff = new Date(diff);
var res = {
  days: days, 
  hours:diff.getHours(), 
  min: diff.getMinutes(), 
  sec: diff.getSeconds()
};
console.log(res);
```

It uses internal `Date` object implementation.
It works, because we need only time to calc.

`new Date(0)` returns us `Date` of `1 Jan 1970` in a time 00:00 GMT.
In the local representation it has timezone shift.
After apply it - we have `Date(0+shift)` which represents 00:00 in our timezone.
So, every time interval incremented to this, give us correct time representation. :)

Comment: Your code does not work. It is still 1.5mins away

Comment: It gives me `{days: 46, hours: 7, min: 42, sec: 10}` when my localtime is `15Nov 16:17:50` How you test it?

Comment: go here http://www.timeanddate.com/counters/newyear.html

Comment: It's pretty same)

Comment: yes it is but there is almost a 1minute difference

Comment: No difference for me.. I think, your localtime shifted. Isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31595/discussion-between-so-readytohelp-and-vp-arth).